# What's the most customizable rank system?

Tags: php, ranking

I need a rank system ( like stars etc.) for my website. Do you know eny scripts that are highly customizable? I would like to use it with a CMS, not as stand alone aplication. Any sugestions will be very helpful

Comment: Are you using a particular CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Rank systems are something, that is very CMS specific. You need to find or order a module for Wolf CMS